# gcloud cannot enable services GCP

Tags: gcloud

I have been trying to install services on a GCP project for hours now to no avail.

```
gcloud services enable cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com
```

However, it keeps coming back as:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.services.enable) UNAVAILABLE: The service is currently unavailable.
```

I have used the same script many times before. I did upgrade gcloud. Has something changed in gcloud?

I use a service-account with roles:

- roles/viewer
- roles/storage.admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely related to a known issue that causes issues when trying to enable API(s) that the Product team is currently working on, you can track the progress of their progress through the [dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/compute/19004).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Google Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/summary), multiple services are affected by different incidents. [Project creation issue dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/?src=VESPA)